# Two type declarations for a single variable in Groovy?

Tags: types, groovy, gradle

While reading the tutorial on Gradle plugins, I cam across the following code:

```
apply plugin: GreetingPlugin

greeting.message = 'Hi from Gradle'

class GreetingPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        // Add the 'greeting' extension object
        project.extensions.create("greeting", GreetingPluginExtension)
        // Add a task that uses the configuration
        project.task('hello') << {
            println project.greeting.message
        }
    }
}

class GreetingPluginExtension {
    def String message = 'Hello from GreetingPlugin'
}
```

My understanding is that the line `def String message = 'Hello from GreetingPlugin'` is declaring two types (both a generic `def` type and a specific `String` type). Removing either of the types seems to allow the script to continue to execute.

Is there any reason why Groovy allows for two type declarations to be made for a single variable? If so, what are the use cases for this language feature and does it serve a specific purpose in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
def String message = 'Hello from GreetingPlugin'
```

is wrong.  The `def` is a waste of characters in this situation as it doesn't do anything

That line is the same as

```
String message = 'Hello from GreetingPlugin'
```

See the [**Def and type** section in this page](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Groovy+style+and+language+feature+guidelines+for+Java+developers)

Answer (score 1):

Use `def` when you don't care about limiting the variable to a specific type, e.g. if the variable needs to support different types at runtime. Otherwise, you can omit `def` and specify a type. There is no benefit to using both.

Read about the semantics here:
http://groovy.codehaus.org/Scoping+and+the+Semantics+of+%22def%22